# update with left join in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to write a query for updating a table that has two left joins. Below is a query in MSSQL, I want to convert it into postgresql. Please help.

```
Update T1 Set  
            T1.Amount = (T1.Amount - T2.Disc) + ((DT1.N_Amount)/2)

    From @Before T1
    Left Join @Before T2 On T1.ID = T2.ID
    Left Join @DiscTable DT1 On T1.PurchID = DT1.Purch_ID
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is possible in postgres too, [the main difference is](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-update.html)

> Note that the target table must not appear in the `from_list`, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the `from_list`).

Your query converted:

```
UPDATE "Before" "T1"
SET "T1"."Amount" = ("T1"."Amount" - "T2"."Disc") + (("DT1"."N_Amount")/2)
FROM "Before" "T2"
LEFT JOIN "DiscTable" "DT1" ON "T1"."PurchID" = "DT1"."Purch_ID"
WHERE "T1"."ID" = "T2"."ID"
```

But why use self-join here? (if `"ID"` is the primary key) I think you can achive your goal simpler, with:

```
UPDATE "Before" "T1"
SET "T1"."Amount" = ("T1"."Amount" - "T1"."Disc") + (("DT1"."N_Amount")/2)
FROM "DiscTable" "DT1"
WHERE "T1"."PurchID" = "DT1"."Purch_ID"
```

**Edit**: [about quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)

Comment: But it is showing error:invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "t1"

Comment: If you mix large & small caps in table/column names, use quoting everywhere or nowhere. If you aren't quote a postgresql identifier it will be converted to small caps to achieve iso sql case insensitiveness. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Note that the semantics of UPDATE FROM and the LEFT JOIN version here are different! UPDATE FROM does INNER JOIN, so if there is no corresponding record in DiscTable, those records don't get updated. In the LEFT JOIN version those get updated with NIL values.